# Copy and paste Excel rows between two workbooks based on criteria from exported Access data

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, copy-paste, delete-row

I have no previous experience in Access, VBA coding or in Excel macros prior to teaching myself the past month via these forums.  Thank you forums and contributors.  I have enjoyed my Access learnings so far, the challenge that it has provided and appreciate any help that I can get.  As such, the code and methods that I have used to this point may well be convoluted and confusing.  I will do my best to provide relevant details and accurate terminology.

I work in a lab and I am creating an Access Form for semi-automated reporting.  Samples are received from clients and are logged into the Excel Table `R&D Log`.  The worksheet is `InProcess`.  Samples are sorted based on the site in which they originate and given a one or two letter site code (G, D, WH, etc.) and an ID "yy-000" in separate Excel columns (i.e. D 18-096). Samples may be submitted for multiple analyses (Metals, Water, Soil, etc.) and may even have multiple rows of reporting if multiple analytes are identified in the sample.  There are several other columns, such as receipt date, reporting date, units, etc.  Once samples are reported, I manually copy and paste them into the `Archived` worksheet, and delete the record and blank row from the `InProcess` worksheet.  Since one sample may have multiple analyses and even more potential results, each record would be reported on a new Excel row (with the same D 18-096 ID number).  Thus, there is not a single unique identifier or primary key for each sample in the current format.  `R&D Log` is updated manually by lab technicians and the worksheet `InProcess` is a linked table in an Access Database.

The Access Database is using two combo boxes on a Form `frmInProcess` to filter a Query `qryInProcess` of the linked table.  The combo boxes are filtering the report destination (one client may receive multiple site codes) and the analysis (reports are separated based on type of analysis).  The Query is also filtering out blank results and blank dates, so only completed samples will appear on the filtered Form.  I have generated VBA code to this point that will export the Form to a .pdf, save the file with unique filename, and open outlook to mail out the report.  I have also managed to export the filtered Form `frmInProcess` to an Excel file `Access Test` (not the linked file).

What I would like to do now is to automate the transfer of completed test results from the Excel worksheet `R&D Log: InProcess` to `R&D Log: Archived` and delete the record from the `InProcess` worksheet.  I am not sure if I can export the filtered Form into a linked Excel table, or if I must use a separate Excel file (or if it even matters for simplicity of code?).  I would now like to read the exported filtered Form in Excel `Access Test`, lookup matching rows in `R&D Log` based on several criteria (site, ID, Analysis, Analyte, Report Date) and automate the transfer of records between `R&D Log` worksheets.  End result being that Access generates reports for completed tests, and the records are removed from `InProcess` testing and transferred to `Archived` testing in Excel.  I am guessing that I may need to close the Access application and perform this in Excel.  Hope this is easy enough to follow.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is too broad for specific suggestion. For ideas on Excel automation, review http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_MainPage.htm. Why not build an Access user interface and abandon Excel? I built a laboratory db and that was what I did. Can download from https://app.box.com/shared/r8nea07sng

Comment: Thank you for your response, June7.  I will certainly look to utilize these resources and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, importing an Excel document into a temporary NEW (or totally empty) Access table is usually the easiest way to go. Then you do not have to worry about cell references like you do in Excel VBA. Even if the Excel document has old data in it with just a few new changes each time, importing it into a temporary Access table could be the simplest way to go, because then you can compare the data in this table with the data in another, permanent Access table and update the latter based on the former.

As far as the original Excel file, if you need to delete rows there, it might be quicker to export a new Excel file with just the data the old one is supposed to end up with, and then use VBA to delete (or - safer! - rename) the old file.

So the development process goes something like this:

1. Save import steps by first importing an Excel file via Access' ribbon options "External Data" (tab) ->"Excel" and when you finish, be sure to check the "Save import steps" box and note the name you give the "saved import" because you will need that in your VBA code.
2. In Access, write a function for deleting the table. The VBA code is:

   ```
   Const cTable = "MyExcelTempTable"
   If TableExists(cTable) Then
     DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, cTable
   End If
   ```

   Now you can test your delete function on the data you imported.
3. Write VBA code to import the same spreadsheet to create the same table:

   ```
   Const cSavedImport = "Import-MyExcelTempTable"

   ' Import the Excel file
   DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport cSavedImport
   ```
4. Write more VBA function(s) to check the imported table for bad data and then to copy it into the permanent table. You might be updating existing records or adding new ones. Either way, you could use Access queries or SQL to do this and run them from VBA.
5. Write a VBA function to rename the old Excel file. (You could use an InputBox if the Excel file name is different each time. I do this for importing Excel files, and I set a default value so I do not have to type as much.)
6. Write a VBA function to export the new version of the Excel file.
7. Make yourself a button on a form that, when clicked, runs a VBA function. Inside that function, run Steps 2 through 6, above.

I am not sure my answer exactly matches what you are trying to do, but hopefully you get enough of a picture of the workflow to figure out the details of what you need.

Comment: Hi Margaret, I have looked at this solution and will see if it makes sense to reconfigure my database.  Currently, the saved import step operation is so slow and that it negates the usefulness of the automated reporting.  If I can solve that issue, I will update on this comment.  Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: Hi Margaret, I took your advice and it has made data manipulation in Excel much easier with the temporary tables unlinked to the database.  Thanks.